# Test-Path returns differetn results in 64Bit and 32Bit powershell

Tags: powershell

I am developing a script which should run under 64 and 32Bit Powershell. Unfortunately it seems that `Test-Path` return different results in 64 and 32 Environment. Both sessions are running under same user, this user has full access on specific registry key.

```
64Bit Powershell
>test-path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ProvisioningServices
True

32Bit Powershell(x86)
>test-path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Citrix\ProvisioningServices
False
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

32-bit programs default to the WOW64 node in the registry, but see it as "normal". If the key does not exist in WOW64 then it is correctly returning false.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I found solution for this Problem under:

[Accessing-remote-x64-registry-from-an-x86x32-server](http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/accessing-remote-x64-registry-from-an-x86x32-server)